# ionic2, cordova run ios works but ionic cordova run ios throws error

Tags: ios, ionic2, splash-screen

In ionic2, `cordova run ios`, but when running `ionic cordova run ios` throwing below error, typescript not recognised.

Same code is working correct for Android.

```
 cordova run ios ->  showing only splash screen and white page, not launching home page.
```

**my config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.hp.tisa" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>      ProjectName </name>
<description>       ProjectName App </description>
<author email="rkjhaw@hotmail.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
   Mobility Development Team    </author>
<content src="index.html" />
<icon density="mdpi" height="57" platform="android" src="resources/android/icon/logo.png" width="57" />
<splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources\android\splash\splash.png" />
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="https://maps.google.com" />
<access origin="http://*.googleapis.com" />
<access origin="https://*.googleapis.com" />
<access origin="http://google.com" />
<access origin="https://google.com" />
<access origin="http://maps.google.com" />
<access origin="http://*.google.com" />
<access origin="content:///*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://10.77.34.183:8100" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="5000" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources\android\splash\splash.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <hook src="hooks/iosrtc-swift-support.js" type="after_platform_add" />
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
    <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
</platform>
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="UseLegacySwiftLanguageVersion" value="true" />
<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
</feature>
<engine name="browser" spec="^4.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="1.0.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="0.8.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.4.3">
    <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="~2.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1" />
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1" />
```

**ionic info -**

```
<rakeshjha$ ionic info
```

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.3.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.3.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic/app-scripts/-/app-scripts-1.2.3.tgz
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.3.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.1 browser 4.1.0 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic-angular/-/ionic-angular-2.0.0-beta.7.tgz
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.10.3
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002 
ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
ios-sim    : 5.0.13
```

Error

```
[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8446 
            ',' expected. 

    L8446:  partition(
    L8447:      callback: ListIterator<T, boolean>): LoDashImplicitArrayWrapper<T[]>;

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8449 
            ']' expected. 

    L8449:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8449 
            ';' expected. 

    L8449:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8452 
            ',' expected. 

    L8451:  partition<W>(
    L8452:      whereValue: W): LoDashImplicitArrayWrapper<T[]>;

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8452 
            '(' expected. 

    L8451:  partition<W>(
    L8452:      whereValue: W): LoDashImplicitArrayWrapper<T[]>;

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8452 
            ',' expected. 

    L8451:  partition<W>(
    L8452:      whereValue: W): LoDashImplicitArrayWrapper<T[]>;

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8452 
            ')' expected. 

    L8451:  partition<W>(
    L8452:      whereValue: W): LoDashImplicitArrayWrapper<T[]>;

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8454 
            ';' expected. 

    L8454:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8454 
            Declaration or statement expected. 

    L8454:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8455 
            ')' expected. 

    L8454:   * @see _.partition
    L8456:  partition(

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8455 
            Expression expected. 

    L8454:   * @see _.partition
    L8456:  partition(

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8456 
            Expression expected. 

    L8456:  partition(
    L8457:      path: string,

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8457 
            '(' expected. 

    L8456:  partition(
    L8457:      path: string,
    L8458:      srcValue: any): LoDashImplicitArrayWrapper<T[]>;

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8457 
            ';' expected. 

    L8456:  partition(
    L8457:      path: string,
    L8458:      srcValue: any): LoDashImplicitArrayWrapper<T[]>;

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8460 
            ';' expected. 

    L8460:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8460 
            ';' expected. 

    L8460:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8460 
            ')' expected. 

    L8460:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8460 
            Expression expected. 

    L8460:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8460 
            ';' expected. 

    L8460:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8460 
            ';' expected. 

    L8460:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8460 
            Declaration or statement expected. 

    L8460:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8466 
            ',' expected. 

    L8466:      interface LoDashImplicitObjectWrapper<T> {

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8466 
            '(' expected. 

    L8466:      interface LoDashImplicitObjectWrapper<T> {

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8466 
            '(' expected. 

    L8466:      interface LoDashImplicitObjectWrapper<T> {

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8466 
            Expression expected. 

    L8466:      interface LoDashImplicitObjectWrapper<T> {

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8467 
            Expression expected. 

    L8466:  interface LoDashImplicitObjectWrapper<T> {
    L8468:       * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8468 
            ',' expected. 

    L8468:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8468 
            ')' expected. 

    L8468:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8473 
            ';' expected. 

    L8474:           * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8473 
            Expression expected. 

    L8474:           * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8474 
            ')' expected. 

    L8474:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8474 
            '(' expected. 

    L8474:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8474 
            '(' expected. 

    L8474:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8474 
            Expression expected. 

    L8474:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8475 
            Expression expected. 

    L8474:   * @see _.partition
    L8476:  partition<TResult>(

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8476 
            ',' expected. 

    L8476:  partition<TResult>(
    L8477:      callback: DictionaryIterator<TResult, boolean>): LoDashImplicitArrayWrapper<TResult[]>;

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8476 
            ')' expected. 

    L8476:  partition<TResult>(
    L8477:      callback: DictionaryIterator<TResult, boolean>): LoDashImplicitArrayWrapper<TResult[]>;

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8493 
            ',' expected. 

    L8493:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8493 
            ']' expected. 

    L8493:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8493 
            ';' expected. 

    L8493:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8493 
            Expression expected. 

    L8493:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8493 
            Expression expected. 

    L8493:   * @see _.partition

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8499 
            ',' expected. 

    L8499:      //_.reduce
    L8500:      interface LoDashStatic {

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8500 
            ';' expected. 

    L8499:  //_.reduce
    L8500:  interface LoDashStatic {

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8500 
            '(' expected. 

    L8499:  //_.reduce
    L8500:  interface LoDashStatic {

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8505 
            ';' expected. 

    L8504:  * consumes the return value of the previous execution. If accumulator is not provided the
    L8505:  * first element of the collection will be used as the initial accumulator value. The callback
    L8506:  * is bound to thisArg and invoked with four arguments; (accumulator, value, index|key, collection).

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8505 
            Expression expected. 

    L8504:  * consumes the return value of the previous execution. If accumulator is not provided the
    L8505:  * first element of the collection will be used as the initial accumulator value. The callback
    L8506:  * is bound to thisArg and invoked with four arguments; (accumulator, value, index|key, collection).

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8506 
            ')' expected. 

    L8505:  * first element of the collection will be used as the initial accumulator value. The callback
    L8506:  * is bound to thisArg and invoked with four arguments; (accumulator, value, index|key, collection).
    L8507:  * @param collection The collection to iterate over.

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8507 
            Declaration or statement expected. 

    L8506:  * is bound to thisArg and invoked with four arguments; (accumulator, value, index|key, collection).
    L8507:  * @param collection The collection to iterate over.
    L8508:  * @param callback The function called per iteration.

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8507 
            Declaration or statement expected. 

    L8506:  * is bound to thisArg and invoked with four arguments; (accumulator, value, index|key, collection).
    L8507:  * @param collection The collection to iterate over.
    L8508:  * @param callback The function called per iteration.

[15:14:08]  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts, line: 8507 
            '(' expected. 

    L8506:  * is bound to thisArg and invoked with four arguments; (accumulator, value, index|key, collection).
    L8507:  * @param collection The collection to iterate over.
    L8508:  * @param callback The function called per iteration.

 =============================================================================
```

**tsconfig.json file**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
 {
"name": "ProjectName",
"author": "rkjhaw@hotmail.com",
"homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.6.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/flashlight": "3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.11.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "1.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "0.8.3",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "~2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git#1.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.1.1",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "node-sass": "4.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.9"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.3.7",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.3.0",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.0",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.64",
    "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "^2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "4.5.2",
    "typescript": "2.3.2"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": [],
"description": "TISA:Toner & Ink Scanning App",
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-console": {},
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "cordova-plugin-email-composer": {},
        "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
            "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
        },
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
        "browser"
    ]
}
```

}

**my updated npm is**

```
npm outdated

Package                                 Current   Wanted   Latest  Location
@angular/common                           2.2.1    4.0.2    4.1.3  TISA
@angular/compiler                         2.2.1    4.0.2    4.1.3  TISA
@angular/compiler-cli                     2.2.1    4.0.2    4.1.3  TISA
@angular/core                           MISSING    4.0.2    4.1.3  TISA
@angular/forms                            2.2.1    4.0.2    4.1.3  TISA
@angular/http                             2.2.1    4.0.2    4.1.3  TISA
@angular/platform-browser                 2.2.1    4.0.2    4.1.3  TISA
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic         2.2.1    4.0.2    4.1.3  TISA
@ionic-native/core                        3.4.4    3.6.1   3.11.0  TISA
@ionic-native/in-app-browser            MISSING    3.6.1   3.11.0  TISA
@ionic-native/status-bar                MISSING    3.6.1   3.11.0  TISA
@ionic/storage                            1.1.7    2.0.1    2.0.1  TISA
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine           1.0.0      git      git  TISA
ionic-angular                      2.0.0-beta.7    3.1.1    3.3.0  TISA
rxjs                               5.0.0-beta.6    5.1.1    5.4.0  TISA
zone.js                                  0.6.12    0.8.9   0.8.11  TISA
@angular/platform-server                  2.2.1    2.2.1    4.1.3  TISA
@ionic-native/camera                      3.4.4    3.4.4   3.11.0  TISA
@ionic-native/email-composer              3.4.4    3.4.4   3.11.0  TISA
@ionic-native/flashlight                  3.4.4    3.4.4   3.11.0  TISA
@ionic-native/geolocation                 3.4.4    3.4.4   3.11.0  TISA
@ionic-native/location-accuracy           3.4.4    3.4.4   3.11.0  TISA
@ionic-native/native-geocoder             3.4.4    3.4.4   3.11.0  TISA
@types/lodash                           4.14.64  4.14.64  4.14.65  TISA
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support          1.6.0    1.6.0    1.6.2  TISA
cordova-plugin-console                    1.0.5    1.0.5    1.0.7  TISA
cordova-plugin-device                     1.1.4    1.1.4    1.1.6  TISA
cordova-plugin-statusbar                  2.2.1    2.2.1    2.2.3  TISA
cordova-plugin-whitelist                  1.3.1    1.3.1    1.3.2  TISA
ionic-gulp-scripts-copy                   2.0.0    2.0.0    2.0.1  TISA
ionic-native                              2.4.1    2.4.1    2.9.0  TISA
node-sass                                 4.5.1    4.5.1    4.5.3  TISA
sw-toolbox                                3.4.0    3.4.0    3.6.0  TISA
```

```
ionic cordova run ios

[WARN] Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin (@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova). Your plugins may be out of date.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Private' of undefined
```

Comment: what is your typescript version? also can you add tsconfig.json?

Comment: tsconfig.json file

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}

Comment: [edit] your question

Comment: "typescript": "2.3.2"

Comment: hmm .. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/index.d.ts#L5 lodash types is 2.2 that could be your problem

Comment: "lodash": "4.17.4",

Comment: no.. check the link.. I meant it used typescript version 2.2

Comment: @suraj, you mean, I have to roll back typescrip to 2.2 from 2.3.2

Comment: I am not sure.. the latest ionic base is using 2.3.3 .. you could try

Comment: now, i'm getting below error


    Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin    
 (@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova). Your plugins may be out of date.
Error: Failed to transpile program

Comment: I guess you will have to raise an issue with lodash..